# Modal style login in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to create a login modal in Meteor similar to what can be seen when the 'login' link is clicked here - http://subtitles.fiddleware.com/. This is the repo for the previously linked site - https://github.com/bmcmahen/Subtitles.

I see in the files for the Subtitles app it's using Session variables and HandlebarJS 'if' statements to get the effect, but I can't seem to grasp what's happening enough to create my own.

If I can get something very basic working, I can go from there. Could anyone offer a simple explanation or example?

**Edit**

I've realized my intent is more to get a modal-like effect using Handlebars and Session variables. Something like this:

```
<template name="overlay">
  {{#if overlay}}
    <div id="templateToShow">
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

Portion of the layout:

```
<template name="layout">
   {{>overlay}}
   {{>navBar}}

   <div>
    {{>yield}}
   </div>
</template>
```

The overlay showing will be based on a click event.

Comment: Are you struggling with showing the overlay or with creating a customized login template?

Comment: Just with showing the overlay. Templates, account creation, etc. I can figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Just a matter of setting 'true' to the session variable. Should have read more closely.

```
<template name='overlay'>
  {{#if overlay}}
  <div class='content'>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

In client:

```
Template.someTemplate.events({
 "click .someLink": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    Session.set("overlay", true);
  }
})

Template.overlay.helpers({
overlay: function() {
  return Session.get("overlay");
 }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

I have a modal working, but not for login.  In this case, the snippet below is the HTML for the modal (For simplicity, I omitted the rest of the template).  It basically flashes the modal for confirmation when on the account management page of my app, the user attempts to delete his/her own administrator access.

```
<template name="manageProject">
  <div class="modal fade" id="checkAdminDelete">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title"><div class="alert alert-danger">Warning:  You are deleting your own administrator access!</div></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You have chosen to delete your own administrator access.  Please confirm, as you will not be able to restore it without the actions of another administrator.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="cancelDelete" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel This Action</button>
        <button type="button" id="confirmDelete" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Confirm This Action</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
 </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Within the javascript that runs this page, I have the following check when the user clicks a button.

```
if (myRecord === Meteor.userId())  // if I am deactivating my own admin access, confirm it
                            $('#checkAdminDelete').modal();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not necessarily after the modal feature of bootstrap, but a modal-like effect using Handlebars. Sort of a

    `<template name='overlay'>
       {{#if overlay}}
        <div id='stuffToShow'>
    .......`